# How to find minimal input crashing the Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that crashes on some inputs. The algoritm breaks an invariant where the Map should contain a value for a given key. It might as well be that the input is invalid.

The function is of type `IntMap.IntMap [Int] -> IO Int`. `IO` is used for random numbers and it crashes on `!` function.

Is it possible to narrow down the error conditions for this function without refactoring it first using Haskell tools like QuickCheck?

Comment: Yup, that sounds exactly like a job for QuickCheck. However, I'd argue that you _should_ refactor this regardless of any errors – needing random numbers is not an excuse for putting your result in `IO` (that's far too general, use [a dedicated monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rvar-0.2.0.3/docs/Data-RVar.html#t:RVar) instead), and `!` is of course always unsafe, you should probably switch to something `lookup`ey.

Comment: As @leftaroundabout says, you should change `!` to `lookup` - this would allow you to produce a custom error message when `lookup` produces `Nothing`. If you have multiple uses of `!`, the error message can be different at each use site, which would give you an easy way to figure out which use is producing the error.

Comment: @user2407038 yes, though GHC-8.2 actually tells you where the offending `!` is located, so this isn't as big of a problem anymore.